# Want to remove an escape character from output of an array

Tags: arrays, regex, node.js, escaping, onesignal

So I have an array thats being returned by a function:

```
console.log(join_ids)

    [ '\'26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7\'',
  '\'64405c09-61d2-43ed-8b15-a99f92dff6e9\'',
  '\'bdc034df-82f5-4cd8-a310-a3c3e2fe3106' ]
```

I was initially able to split the array using this function:

```
join_ids = join_ids.split(',');
```

I want to try and remove the backslashes from the output and this is the function I'm using:

```
join_ids = join_ids.replace(/\\/g, "");

console.log(typeof(join_ids));
object
```

I am trying to send a notification and the parameters in it are:

```
let message = {
  app_id: `${app_id}`,
  contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
  filters: [{'field': 'tag', 'key': 'userId', 'relation': '=', 'value': `${join_ids[0]}`}],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1
};
```

The response I'm seeing is the following:

console.log(message);

```
{ app_id: '****************',
  contents: { en: 'Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!' },
  filters: 
   [ { field: 'tag',
       key: 'userId',
       relation: '=',
       value: '\'26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7\'' } ],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1 }
```

I want the respone to be:

```
value: '26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7'
```

What might I be doing wrong?? Thanks!

Comment: `join_ids.replace(/[\']/g, '')` should work. Also, you need to loop over the `join_ids` array and apply this to each array item and not the array itself.

Comment: Do you mind showing me an example of how I can loop over it, like a for loop?

Comment: var a = a.map(function(val, idx){ 
       return val.replace(/'/g, "");        
    });

Comment: Can I also iterate over that with some loop inside of that?

Comment: The map function will loop over each value of your original array, and return a new array with each value properly escaped - as returned by the nested function. You shouldn't need any extra iteration as far as escaping your content.

Comment: @IAmDranged Thanks for your input, I have tried the following in my code:

`   var join_ids_map = join_ids.map(function (join_ids, err) {
      return join_ids.replace(/\\/g, "")
   });`

Unfortunately same result, what do you think might be wrong?

Comment: You didn't use proper pattern for escaping as part of the first argument for the replace function - you used \\ instead of '

Comment: I'm actually trying to escape both, the \ and the '

Comment: Sure, but in this instance the backslash is actually just a metachacacter that is just there to tell the Javascript interpreter that the apostroph just after it should be understood literally - rather than interpreted as the end of the string. The end result of the string '\'26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7\'' after interpretation by the engine is '26c14292-a181-48bd-8344-73fa9caf65e7', so you just have to work from there and escape the apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by using a `replace()` with a simple regex and a tagged template literal when you're inserting the value into your message object as a template literal.

```
function stripEscape (strings, ...values) {
  return values[0].replace(/\\`/g, '');
}

let message = {
  app_id: `${app_id}`,
  contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
  filters: [{'field': 'tag', 'key': 'userId', 'relation': '=', 'value': stripEscape`${join_ids[0]}`}],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1
}
```

If you do not want to use the tagged template literal, you can chain the replace on your template literal paramter.

```
let message = {
  app_id: `${app_id}`,
  contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
  filters: [{'field': 'tag', 'key': 'userId', 'relation': '=', 'value': `${join_ids[0].replace(/\\`/g, '')}`}],
  ios_badgeType: 'Increase',
  ios_badgeCount: 1
}
```

Hope this helps get what you were wanting, if you run into problems with it...let me know as I am still learning how to use ES6 features effectively.